# C# - Silverlight - MVVM

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I want to use UserControl as the base for my views, but I cannot add functionality to my views because they are based on UserControl.

How do I create my own view class by using a subclassed version of UserControl.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot add functionality. Pretty much every view in MVVM examples are user controls. Or is silverlight missing something to do this?

Comment: Please include a code example of what you are doing or trying, so we can better assist.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that you want to have a base class for views which is itself a subclass of UserControl, but also want to maintain support for the Visual Studio UI designer for WPF?  I've tried doing this myself, but was unable to find a way to get Visual Studio to support UI design when the base class wasn't UserControl, but was a custom subclass of UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put them in the subclassed version of UserControl, and implement an interface which denotes the abilities the class has, so the ViewModel can be used with any type of View by simply using the interface.

Comment: Are you talking about having a reference to your View from your ViewModel? Even through an interface this is one of the most hotly debated MVVM issues. Personally, I would look into implementing a Messenger Pattern like MVVMlight Messenger, so the View and ViewModel stay as losely coupled as possible.